# Show / Hide HTML tag using BehaviorSubject value

Tags: angular, angular8

Using Angular 8 I access a BehaviorSubject as follows:

```
this.myBehavioSubject.subscribe(parameter => {
  console.log(parameter);
});
```

Where `parameter` value is `show` or `hide`.

The `myBehaviorSubject` is also accessible in the component's HTML.

How can I show / hide a P tag using the myBehaviorSubject.parameter value:

```html
<p *ngIf="????">Message</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would you rather suggest to use async pipe in the template. Answers above can cause memory leaks if you will not unsubscribe from observable in onDestroy method. Async pipe handles unsubscribe instead of you.

In the component you can type:

```
showMessage: Observable<boolean> = this.myBehaviorSubject
                                     .asObservable()
                                     .pipe(map(status => status === 'show'));
```

and in the template:

```
<p *ngIf="showMessage | async">Message</p>
```

Comment: As with all things..it depends. Not every observable has to be unsubscribed from. Infinitely running observables have to be unsubscribed for your mentioned reason.

Comment: yeah, agree. However, I told in general

Comment: Why don't we use this.myBehavioSubject.value in html?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a variable in typescript file and use it in HTML:

```
let show = false;
this.myBehavioSubject.subscribe(parameter => {
  console.log(parameter);
  this.show  = parameter == 'show' ? true : false;
});
```

HTML:

```
<p *ngIf="show">Message</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign 'parameter' value to some global variable in order to bind it to html

```
this.myBehavioSubject.subscribe(parameter => {
console.log(parameter);
this.value = parameter;
});
```

On html

```
<p *ngIf="value == 'show">Message</p>
```

Or you can do

```
this.myBehavioSubject.subscribe(parameter => {
console.log(parameter);
if(parameter == 'show'){
this.value = true;    
} else {
this.value = false;    
}
});
```

On html

```
<p *ngIf="value">Message</p>
```

Comment: Please check your parameter value then. is it returning you a simple string or an object or something else?